# VS Code Intellisense/autocomplete without importing file

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

Let's say I have 3 simple files:

app.js

```
const A = require('./a');
const B = require('./b');

let first = new A("hello");
let second = new B(first);
```

a.js

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {*} val Value
 */
function a(val) {
  this.val = val;
}

module.exports = a;
```

b.js

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {a} a - a instance
 */
function b(a) {
  this.a = a;
  console.log(this.a.val); // no hint / autocomplete suggestions
}

module.exports = b;
```

Is it possible to get Intellisense to show fields/methods of class "a" in file "b.js" without importing/requiring it when it's passed as argument?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/javascript-intellisense